# SQL window funktion ORDER BY 2 columns, sum over all previous rows in google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sum, sql-order-by, window-functions

In google BigQuery, I want to `sum(value)` over all rows where `condition1` is smaller than in the current row AND `condition2` is smaller than in the current row. Note that the dataset is ordered by `condition1` so all previous rows regarding `condition1` are smaller than the current row's value of `condition1`.
Also, I have a very large dataset, so a self-join is not possible with respect to calculation time.

Here is an example:

```
-- | condition1 | condition2 | value | expected_output |
-- |------------|------------|-------|-----------------|
-- |     1      |      2     |    1  |        0        |
-- |     1      |      2     |    1  |        0        |
-- |     2      |      1     |    1  |        0        |
-- |     2      |      2     |    1  |        0        | 
-- |     2      |      3     |    1  |        2        | --> sum over rows 1 and 2
-- |     3      |      2     |    1  |        1        | --> sum over row 3
-- |     3      |      2     |    1  |        1        | --> sum over row 3
-- |     4      |      5     |    1  |        7        | --> sum over rows 1-7
-- |     5      |      4     |    1  |        7        | --> sum over rows 1-7
-- |     6      |      7     |    1  |        9        | --> sum over rows 1-9
```

note that in this example `value` is always 1 to make the example easy, bis `value` can be any number.

I tried with:

```
SUM(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY condition1, condition2 RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

but the problem is, that only the first condition `condition1` is "checked". It orders by `condition2`, but still, all rows are considered in the sum, even if the value in `condition2` is larger than the value in the current row.

Some query to work with where I already tested the behavior of different `windows`:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT
    (1 as condition1, 2 as condition2,1 as value), 
    (2,1,1),
    (3,2,1),
    (2,2,1),
    (5,4,1),
    (4,5,1),
    (2,3,1),
    (6,7,1),
    (3,2,1)
  ])
)
SELECT
  *
  ,SUM(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY condition1, condition2 RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as test_1
  ,SUM(VALUE) OVER (ORDER BY condition2, condition1 RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as test_2
  ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY condition1, condition2) as rank1
  ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY condition2, condition1) as rank2
FROM data
ORDER BY condition1
```

Thanks!

Update:
Thanks to @Mikhail Berlyants input I noted that my question was not phrased correctly. I updated the question and the example now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach - I know it looks little crazy  - but just try - here I am trying to partition calculation by condition2 and then join back to original data

```
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY condition1, condition2) AS pos
  FROM your_table
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT condition2, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(pos, condition1, value) ORDER BY condition1) r
  FROM temp1
  GROUP BY condition2
), temp3 AS ( 
  SELECT a.condition1, t1.condition2, SUM(b.value) result, a.pos 
  FROM temp2 t1 LEFT JOIN temp2 t2 ON t1.condition2 > t2.condition2,
  t1.r a JOIN t2.r b ON a.condition1 > b.condition1
  GROUP BY a.pos, condition1, condition2
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(pos) 
FROM temp1 LEFT JOIN temp3 USING(pos, condition1, condition2)
```

if applied to sample data in your updated question - output is

[image]

Second option to try

```
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT condition1, condition2, SUM(value) value
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY condition1, condition2
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT condition2, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(condition1, value) ORDER BY condition1) r
  FROM temp1
  GROUP BY condition2
), temp3 AS ( 
  SELECT a.condition1, t1.condition2, SUM(b.value) result
  FROM temp2 t1 LEFT JOIN temp2 t2 ON t1.condition2 > t2.condition2,
  t1.r a JOIN t2.r b ON a.condition1 > b.condition1
  GROUP BY condition1, condition2
)
SELECT * 
FROM your_table LEFT JOIN temp3 USING(condition1, condition2)
```

with same output of course

While second version has better chances to survive it has little limitation vs. first version in this answer  - namely - first version very easy to modify for condition mentioned in your question - when condition2 `<=` versus just `<` (btw, I don't see now this in your question so i might mixing something here - sorry :o)

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail! Approach 1 did not run through within a reasonable time. With a ~10m rows dataset, version 2 took a bit less than 2 min which is already awesome and really fast compared but I'm afraid it won't run through for the entire dataset. Still your thinking is impressive. I tried to understand the approach now for quite some time and still did not completely get it :D. Btw you are right with the <= vs <. I might have accidentally deleted this when updating the example in my question.

Comment: cool. great. thank you for confirming. and yes - result you describe is somewhat as expected

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option  is left join as in below example

```
select any_value(t1).*, 
  ifnull(sum(t2.value), 0) output 
from your_table t1
left join your_table t2
on t1.ts > t2.ts
and t1.condition1 > t2.condition1
and t1.condition2 > t2.condition2
group by format('%t', t1)
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: whenever you say about `previous rows` you must have some column that define the order of rows. hope you have such in your table - it can be date or timestamp, etc. I added ts column as a such

Also note : in row #9 output should be 7 and not 8 as presented in your question!

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail for your input. I noted that I did not phrase my question correctly and also showed an incorrect example. You are right about the need for a column that defines the order, actually `condition1` should be this column. I updated my example as well. Regarding the self-join: Unfortunately my dataset is too large so it won't run through. I tested that already. Do you have any idea how to make it faster?

Comment: ok. this slightly improves our chances. will look again later in a day :o)

Comment: what cardinality of condition1 and condition2 (how many distinct values for each) and what their nature, min/max, etc. we need to find something that will help to avoid linear processing - so looking for more info/details

Comment: condition1 has roughly 750k distinct values which I can transform to integer with [min,max]:[0,750000]. condition2 has 5k, floating point number with [min,max]: [0.01,100000]. also: I already reduced the precision of condition2: for all values > 10 I rounded up to the next integer.